# 3 divs - make the middle one responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've some problem with creating a responsive header, I placed 3 div in a wrapper (left div - logo, middle div - image, right div - logout image).

Now I would like when user visit my page from Tablet (small resolution) the image inside the middle div will be responsive and will get smaller.

But the problem is when I shrink the page to small resolution (by shrinking the browser or visit the page from Tablet) the right div going under and if I shrink more also the second div.

here is my code:

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
<div class="left">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="img/logo.png" />
    </a>
</div>
<div class="middle">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="img/middle.png" />
    </a>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="img/logout.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

```
.left {
   float:left;
}
.middle{
   float:left;
    width:100%;
 }
  .right{
      float:right;
 }
```

- I want that the middle image will be responsive so its will be smaller and smaller when I shrink the page size and that nothing from the header will break under

Comment: edit: Thats because the middle div has a width of 100% so there is no room for the right div to float on the same line.

Comment: I'd love to live in a web environment that removes that stupid float property. *it doesn't help* when it comes to you learning positioning and display properties instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

CSS:

```
.left {
    float:left;
}
.middle {
    display:table-cell;
}
.right {
    float:right;
}
img{
    max-width:100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"> <a href="#">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/1/" />
    </a>

    </div>
    <div class="right"> <a href="#">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/3/" />
    </a>

    </div>
    <div class="middle"> <a href="#">Dummy text</a>        </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/525/ // with text

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/526/  // with images

**Note:** Change the html layout. Place the floating div together. See the html

Comment: Looking good! thanks! but does it work if inside the middle div there will be image? I need the middle div to contain image that will be responsive?

Comment: Yes it will. you will need to add "max-width:100%" to img css so that it doesn't overflow. Also you'll have to adjust the image alignment as per your layout. That should be easy

Answer (score 1):

Given the layout you've described, I would tend to forgo `float:` entirely and use `position:relative;` and `position:absolute;` and `margin` instead:

```css
.wrapper {
position: relative;
height: 122px;
border:1px solid rgba(255,0,0,1);
}

.middle {
position: relative;
margin:10px 224px;
height: 100px;
border:1px solid rgba(0,255,0,1);
}

.left {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 10px;
width:200px;
height: 100px;
border:1px solid rgba(0,0,255,1);
}

.right {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
right: 10px;
width:200px;
height: 100px;
border:1px solid rgba(0,0,255,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"> 
<div class="left">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="img/logo.png" />
    </a>
</div>
<div class="middle">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="img/middle.png" />
    </a>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="img/logout.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.left {


 float:left;
    width:20%
}
.middle{
   float:left;
    width:60%;
 }
  .right{
      float:right;
    width:20%;
 }
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.

Comment: Give the main div width 100% e.g wrapper{width:100%} then divide it in three part as i mentioned in my answer

Comment: it will automatically adjust the width when you see it on tablet or phone or pc

Answer (score 0):

try this : http://jsfiddle.net/76kMN/22/

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
<div class="left">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://www.92pixels.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/ldi6.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
<div class="middle">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://cdn4.colorlib.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/02/Olympic-logo.png" />
    </a>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://www.92pixels.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/ldi6.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>

.left {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}

.wrapper {
    float: left;

    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.middle{
   float:left;
    width:60%;
 }
img {
    max-width: 100%;max-height: 100%;
}
  .right{
      float:right;   width: 20%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set widths for left/right sidebars

```css
.wrapper {
    overflow:auto;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.left {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
}
.middle {
    padding:0 120px 0 100px; /* padding as the sidebar widths */
    text-align:center;
}
.middle img {
    max-width:100%;
}
.right {
    float:right;
    width:120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=left" /></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="right">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x200&text=right" /></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="middle">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/450x350&text=center" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/xcdd8uwq/